# Container scrolls despite hidden scrollbar

Tags: css

I have a carousel which should only scroll horizontally. The items in the carousel scale on hovering, which cause them to be bigger than the container and in turn enables vertical scrolling despite the container having css propery `overflow-y: hidden;`. The carousel height should fit the height of its childrens initial state, not be set explicitly. Example can be found here [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rp9yw86v/12/)

How can I disable the vertical scrolling entirely, even when the content grows?

```css
#carousel {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: teal;
  width: 300px;
  /* height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; */
}

#carousel > div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#carousel > div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#carousel > div:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

#carousel > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Added .gif of what it looks like for me in Chrome 63, Ubuntu 17.10
[image]

Comment: i don't see any scroll on hover

Comment: @TemaniAfif The scrollbar doesn't appear, but it is vertically scrollable. Try hovering over an item, swap a bit back and forward between items and you will be able to scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try setting overflow-y: hidden to the main body:

```
html, body{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvtp2ud7/1/

if you want body able to scroll Y, try setting overflow property specifically to children too:

https://jsfiddle.net/qvtp2ud7/2/

But it seems a cache issue more than an overflow behaviour. Clear cache, try with different browsers and update your browsers if needed, maybe your version have some glitch.

Comment: Does that work for you? It doesn't for me with Chrome 63, Ubuntu 17.10.
But more importantly it I guess I still need to be able to scroll on the body..

Comment: he doesn't specified this. It's not scrollable to me on Chrome canary 66.0.3357.0 (Build oficial) canary (64 bits) over Windows 10.

Comment: edited with another option, it must not be scrollable anyway with him code but... i can test it on different browsers on iOS, ubuntu, windows and Android but i'm sure that there will not be any Y-axis scroll.

Comment: I would be very happy if you could report your test on Ubuntu. I expect that you will experience the issue.
I have tested on windows and see it is indeed not scrollable there.

Comment: well, if you put an overflow-y: hidden, it's known that it must not take vertical scroll in any case. Which version of ubuntu and which browser (and version) are you using? 
I'll try it in few minutes on ubuntu chrome and FF, and on mac late this evening if i can..

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with Chrome 64.0.3282.167 and FF 58.0.2, still not seeing the issue... It's not vertical scrollable to me

Comment: I will try to make a GIF when I have time

Comment: I edited my question with a gif. Notice how I start by flipping back and forth between the first 2 items before I can scroll vertically.

Comment: can you try to update chrome to latest version and try it on firefox too?

Comment: I can't reproduce on firefox, all is good there. But the error remains on chrome 64.0.3282.186, Ubuntu 17.10.. 
I guess I will just ignore it if it's only a problem for ubuntu or better yet only the experimental version of ubuntu.

Comment: it seems to be a rendering error instead of code issues. I'll recommend you to test in a stable enviornment and if it's ok as it's to me, let it as is.